# When Orchestrator is called from an EventHub trigger , how to get webhook to query the instance statuses

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I am trying to call durable orchestrator on Event Hub trigger. I am able to do so.
Do I still get a webhook to query the statuses of the durable orchestrator instances?
Or I need to introduce a http trigger in between in order to get the webhook endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Event Grid Trigger to Start Orchestration then the response will be sent to Event Grid, so I do not think you can capture it.

- If your Event has something unique that you can use as a InstanceId
- Then, you can start Durable Function using an overload of StartNewAsync that accepts instance ID
- Lastly, you can create a HTTP Trigger that accepts Instance ID and use GetStatusAsync to get status or use CreateCheckStatusResponse to generate Status URLs

Also, the status URL can be built manually, the key in status URL is Storage Account Key.